# iPhone App: integrate Location based service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, location

In iPhone App I want to integrate Location Based services i.e. I want to fetch the name of nearby restaurant in form of array and display in my app.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

See [the Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) for how to retrieve your current GPS position and so on.

Once you have your GPS position, there is no magic and nothing build-in to "retrieve a list of nearby xxxxx": you need a dedicated API for that (a database with all the restaurants and their GPS position, for example, and a request to your API will fetch the ones in your database near the queried GPS position).

You may of course use existing WebServices for that too, like performing a request to Google Search API; actually it depends on your needs (which info you need to retrieve, at which format, how qualified they need to be...)

Answer (score 0):

This will be perfect for you, and you can google anything that he doesn't cover but he is very good http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should try following URL for fetching the nearby restaurants:

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Restaurant&mrt=yp&sll=Latitude,Longitudeg&output=kml

You should pass latitude and longitude of area near by which you need restaurants in above Latitude and Longitude field. You will get kml file for it which you will have to parse.

Comment: that will be kml file which you can parse with NSXMLParser